# Include 2 shell script in pom.xml maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I have 2 shell script download.sh and delete.sh, Also I have a plugin to move the folder.

My Expectations

```
    1. Download through download.sh
    2. Copy folder to resource folder
    3. Delete folder using Delete.sh
```

But by using below plugin, I am not able to perform 1st and 2nd operation directly it is executing Delete.sh.

How can I achieve run both shell script and copy folder in above order.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-exec</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/DownloadScript.sh</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/MyFolder</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>MyFolder</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-delete</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/DeleteRepo.sh</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: What kind of download are trying to do? Why not using dependencies? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am downloading one repo and after using that I wanted to delete it

Comment: What are you downloading there? Dependencies? This is done by Maven automatically. So no need to have a shell script for that? What is the purpose of that? Please answer the questions...I don't see the need to execute such shell scripts during a Maven build...